# How to create JSON API with RethinkDB as backend and Grape gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rethinkdb, ruby-grape

I want to create an API application with RethinkDB as backend and Grape gem to create the APIs. I have read the docs of Nobrainer Ruby ORM. Just like [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-great-apis-grape/), could somebody give me a starting points or guidelines on how to go about creating this API application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This book is what you need: [API On Rails](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book) written by Abraham Kuri Vargas. This is the best resource so far. You can learn how to build an API pretty fast with token authentication as well.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a great resource. Going through it now. :)